# Pivot Pandas dataframe and take missed values from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two dataframes:

```
table1

id |  time |  status
-----------------------
1  | 10:00 | conn     | 
1  | 10:01 | disconn  | 
2  | 10:02 | conn     | 
2  | 10:03 | disconn  | 
3  | 10:04 | conn     | 


table2

id |  time |
------------
3  | 10:05 |
```

If there is no disconn time value for ceratin id then take it from table2.
How to get wished result ?

```
id | conn | disconn|
--------------------
1  | 10:00| 10:01  |
2  | 10:02| 10:03  |
3  | 10:04| 10:05  |
```

Comment: I was answering as comment to your other question but you deleted before I could post, I updated my answer below instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Serie.map.html):

```
out = (table1.pivot(index='id', columns='status', values='time')
             .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )

out['disconn'] = out['disconn'].fillna(out['id'].map(table2.set_index('id')['time']))
```

Variant for the second step:

```
m = out['disconn'].isna()
out.loc[m, 'disconn'] = out.loc[m, 'id'].map(table2.set_index('id')['time'])
```

Output:

```
   id   conn disconn
0   1  10:00   10:01
1   2  10:02   10:03
2   3  10:04   10:05
```

If you have duplicated ids/status:

```
out = (table1.assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(['id', 'status']).cumcount())
             .pivot(index=['id', 'n'], columns='status', values='time')
             .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```